# Static IP addressing issue in Ubuntu on BeagleBoneBlack Rev C

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip

I have my BBB configured to use a static IP address using the following in the file /etc/network/interfaces:

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
```

This seems to work ok on boot, but when the ethernet cable is unplugged and then plugged back in, I lose the IP address.  Any ideas what's going on here?

Another weird symptom: If I boot the BBB with the network cable unplugged, but the switch it's plugged into off, I'll get my static IP.  But, when I turn the switch on, I'll get a DHCP-assigned address.  This is even though I have it configured with a static IP address.

One last thing.  If I ifdown etho, the interface will be gone when I do an ifconfig.  If I wait a few seconds, though, and then re-run ifconfig, it will reappear, without an IP address.  (Before I disabled IPv6, I used to get a IPv4 DHCP address in this case... weird).  When that happens, I get a message like this in /var/log/messages:

```
Apr 23 20:32:06 beaglebone kernel: [  737.170172] libphy: 4a101000.mdio:00 - Link is Up - 100/Full
Apr 23 20:32:06 beaglebone kernel: [  737.170304] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

Here's my uname -a:

```
root@beaglebone:/etc# uname -a
Linux beaglebone 3.8.13-bone47 #1 SMP Fri Apr 11 01:36:09 UTC 2014 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: remove allow-hotplug

Answer (score 1):

I believe I may have figured it out.

It turns out that wicd is installed and running.  On bootup, my /etc/network/interfaces was in charge, but when the cable was unplugged, wicd took over.  Editing /etc/wicd/wired-settings to include my static IP did the trick.

It's not great that is configured in two places, but I've added a pointer in /etc/network/interfaces to indicate that this is what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `allow-hotplug eth0`

Try this config:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```